# Send mail from my web application

Tags: java, struts2, email

I have a feature in my web app like I have to send mails from the server to many email ids (some kind of notification stuff)

my web application is implemented in struts2. Possibly I have to use javamail api i guess. I am completely new to this javamail and sending mail from server. what basic steps I need to do to setup a mail server in windows, contact the server from my java web app. What api i should I use ?
The web has very limited tutorials on javamail and they are damn complicated too.
Is there any other api other than javamail by which I can send mail from my java struts2 web app.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_Mail_Transport_System) for your mail server. The [javamail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) is pretty straightforward. Just create a utility class to simplify the javamail API further.

Answer (score 1):

for this use smtp in your jsp page...
for more refrence go to www.java2s.com